# Ansible template - Destination directory does not exist error

Tags: templates, copy, ansible

I am new to ansible and I am using a template statement in my playbook to copy a file from my local machine to a remote machine. I get an error saying the destination directory does not exist, but it is there very much.

I am using Centos 6.5 version (both my local and remote). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the the task and the error.

Comment: Check permissions on target directory. Maybe it's not writable for ansible user.

Comment: It was my fault. I gave the wrong destination path

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Create the destination directory with Ansible -

```
- name: Create a directory if it does not exist
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /etc/some_directory
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
```

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/file_module.html